# Tooltipster close button

Tags: jquery, button, tooltip, hide, tooltipster

I'm using [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#advanced), and have a tooltip which shows when a menu button is clicked (this bit works OK).
I'm having problems closing the tooltip with a close button within the tooltip though.

I must be missing something pretty simple.

**HTML**

```
<span class="tooltip-email-share"> Stuff </span>

<!-- is triggered by this link -->
<ul>
 <...>
 <li><a class="menu-share"></a></li>
 <...>
</ul>
```

**HTML for tooltip** (just in case)

```
<div class="tt-email-share">
    <span class="tt-close"></span>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <form>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// initiates the tooltip - trigger set to custom & autoClose is false, so it wont close without pressing the close button.

$('.tooltip-email-share').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-html-shadow',
        interactive: 'true',
        autoClose: 'false',
        position: 'bottom',
        speed: '200',
        trigger: 'custom',
    content: $('HTML Stuff in here')
    });

// Shows the tooltip (this bit works a charm)

    $('.menu-share').click(function(){
        $('.tooltip-email-share').tooltipster('show');    
    }); 

// *should* close the tooltip (doesn't work)

    $('.tt-close').click(function(){
        $('.tooltip-email-share').tooltipster('hide');
    });
```

Comment: I've figured out that it will close if that code is attached to a button outside of the tooltip. Not really sure what to do at this point..

Comment: I haven't tried this plugin but found this to close a tooltip. Hope it helps. $('.tooltip-email-share').data('plugin_tooltipster').hideTooltip();

Comment: No dice unfortunately, thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 8):

Solution is (props to a colleague for helping me out with this one):

The close button didn't exist at the point in time I was targeting it. So I had to add a functionReady function to run the on-click script once the tooltip was loaded.

Works perfect.

```
$('.tooltip-email-share').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-html-shadow',
    interactive: 'true',
    autoClose: 'false',
    position: 'bottom',
    speed: '200',
    trigger: 'custom',
    content: $('HTML stuff in here'),
// new function here 
    functionReady: function(){ 
        $('.tt-close').click(function(){
            $('.tooltip-email-share').tooltipster('hide');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I just posted a solution that probably works in your Reddit thread too, although this works just fine!

Comment: Oh rad! I was about to check there. Thanks for taking the time to look into it :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the tooltipster function parameters so you don't have to name your selectors.

This is the only way it worked for me because my tooltip was generated inside ajax loaded content. The tooltip object gives you access to the tooltip DOM, and using the origin object works better for dynamic content, classes, or ids.

```
functionReady: function(origin, tooltip) {
    $(tooltip).on( 'click', '. tt-close', function(){
        $(origin).tooltipster('hide');
    });
}
```